# Scrolling distance of FigureCanvas

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gef, draw2d

I am doing an eclipse plug-in using GEF for drawing graphs. I am using a FigureCanvas to display the graphs. When I am scrolling canvas is there any way to get the distance that the canvas was scrolled?

Answer (score 1):

You can translate the coordinates from the scrolled figure to the relative coordinate system.  Try this:

```
org.eclipse.draw2d.geometry.Point p = new org.eclipse.draw2d.geometry.Point(e.x,e.y);
root.translateToRelative(p);
```

Then use the p.x and p.y when referring to the coordinate